# Generics unresolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, objectify

How can I get T to resolve in eclipse?

```
public T get(Class cl, String id) {
        return ofy().load().type(cl).id(id).get();

    }
```

Is this not going to work in Java 7?

I'm trying to upgrade objectify from 3 to 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking how to make the method (and `Class` argument) generic. Something like,

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> cl, String id) {
    return ofy().load().type(cl).id(id).get();
}
```

Generics were introduced in Java 5 (so Java 5+, including Java 7).

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare it first.

```
public <T> T get(Class<?> cl, String id) {
        return ofy().load().type(cl).id(id).get();

    }
```

Or

```
public class MyClass<T> {
   public T get(Class<?> cl, String id) {
            return ofy().load().type(cl).id(id).get();

        }
}
```